# Apply a multivariate function over two lists

Tags: r, apply, tapply

I have a mapping function as follows,

```
sub.func <- function(x,y){
  if(agrepl(x,y)){
    return(x)
  }
  else{
    return(y)
  }
}
```

now I want to apply this to compare two lists of different size, say `myList1` and `myList2`, such that for each element of `myList1`, `sub.func` will look for a match in `myList2` and if yes will replace by the element of `myList2`. So that all elements of `myList2` are mapped to.  How can I achieve this without using loops? Any variant of apply functions can be used?

e.g.

```
myList1 <- c("a b", "c d", "e f")

myList2 <- c("1", "a b d", "d", "e f g h", "2 3 a c d", "c g")
```

desired output is same length as myList2 but mapped to myList1 wherever possible

```
output <- c("1", "a b", "d", "e f", "c d", "c g")
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include sample input and desired output just to make clear what you want and provide a simple way to test potential solutions. See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: That will likely trigger a warning and give incorrect results because `agrepl` is a vectorized function.

Comment: Returns a vector result, I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Reduce` function for this

```
myList1 <- c("a b", "c d", "e f")
myList2 <- c("1", "a b d", "d", "e f g h", "2 3 a c d", "c g")

Reduce(function(vals, find) {vals[grep(find, vals)]<-find; vals}, myList1, myList2)
# [1] "1"   "a b" "d"   "e f" "c d" "c g"
```